# Debug TYPO3 site configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, symfony-routing

I have to update a complicated RealURL configuration to the new site configuration in V9. I get 404 errors and unwanted redirects, so I need something to debug the routing.

While debugging through core files I realized TYPO3 uses Symfony Routing, and Symfony has already a debug interface: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html
Is it possible to use it for debugging TYPO3 routes as well? If yes, can you tell me how to do this?

If not, some hints about the main routing classes/functions would be helpfull, so I can write myself some PHP debug output. My problems are with routeEnhancers and aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you point to what is the issue exactly here?

- Redirects when calling "regular" pages?
- Issues with Route Enhancers? When resolving the URL?

As Symfony Routing works with static routes w/ modifiers by default ("I have a list of 100 URL endpoints"), and TYPO3 has dynamic routes (populated by the database) the simple debug tool from Symfony Routing does not work here.

When it comes to resolving, the "PageResolver" PSR-15 middleware and the "PageRouter" is a good start when debugging.

Comment: Issue is a complex REST Api in realurl, and I want to bring it step by step to V9. ExtBase Controller, Lookup Table, and so on. All I get is 404 without any information currently, and it is all new to me, so I really could use some debug output.

Comment: Debugging the PageResolver and PageRouter functions was the right suggestion, works now

Answer (score 0):

I had my configuration in an included, external file.

In this case even Parsing-Errors are omitted!!

To test if its valid you can copy&paste it into the main config.yaml.